# Is C# Font.Height thread safe

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am running a .Net profiler on a piece of code (which contains Font.Height get method) which is accessed by multiple threads, the profiler shows that Font.Height is blocked (I can see in the call stack of the profiler calling waitforsingleobject). I understand that, in any case I should not call the Font.Height in a method which is called from multiple threads but my question is what is happening internally when this call is made from multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without looking into the native code that the .NET code wraps, but any public static members of Font class are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

You can browse the code at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Advanced/Font.cs#7c692e253eb24b01

Search for GetHeight functions to see the details. It calls into GDI, though, so it doesn't really help much in understanding whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

Font.Height is read-only, hence other threads cannot change it, and consequently it should be safe to call it from any thread.